dtaidistance.dtw.distance – how to limit DTW only in one direction from one time-series to the other?
The Python package DTAIDistance allows the computation of the dynamic time warping (DTW) distance via dtaidistance.dtw.distance (https://dtaidistance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/dtw.html).
It is possible to adjust how DTW connects sampling points from time-series A) with sampling points from time-series B) such as via the window and max_step parameters in the function.
Question: Is it possible to tell the function that it should only connect a sampling/data point from time-series A) with time-series B) if the data point in time-series A) precedes B) in time?
Phrased differently: Imagine I know a priori that data point 150 in time-series A) precedes data point 150 in time-series B), so that DTW should not connect data point 150 (of series A) with, say, data point 146, 147, 148, or 149 (of series B), but only with data point 150 or upwards.
I need a constraining parameter for DTW to prohibit this asymmetry in time so to speak.

I can't give you a very good Python answer, but from the documentation you shared I'm not sure that will be possible. I've done this in R with a custom window function that depends on the indices along the warping path, so it wouldn't work if the function only accepts a single specific integer.
